# GRDBCipher has no member insert

Tags: sql, swift, sqlite

Hello I am having an issues with GRDBCipher in Swift.  When try to use a record it gives me an error Value of type "The Struct" has no member insert.  I also get the error for update.

```
struct PointOfInterest {
        var id: Int64?
        var title: String
        var isFavorite: Bool
        var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    }

    // snip: turn PointOfInterest into a "record" by adopting the protocols that
    // provide fetching and persistence methods.
    do{
        try dbQueue.inDatabase { db in
            var berlin = PointOfInterest(
                id: nil,
                title: "Berlin",
                isFavorite: false,
                coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.52437, longitude: 13.41053))

            try berlin.insert(db) //error here
            berlin.id // some value

            berlin.isFavorite = true
            try berlin.update(db) //error here

            // Fetch [PointOfInterest] from SQL
            let pois = try PointOfInterest.fetchAll(db, "SELECT * FROM pointOfInterests")// error on fectchAll
        }
    } catch {
        print("broke")
    }
```

Comment: Catching errors and then doing nothing with them is a bad idea.  What's the whole stack trace?  That's basic debugging.

Comment: Yes, I knew this about error tracking. Since this is only a demo of the code to show everyone where the errors are occurring and the original example code that was supposed to work did not have any error catching at all.  Now does any one know what is the issues with GRDB since the record are supposed to already have this coding included?  Thank You

Comment: Have a look at GRDB documentation about records. You'll get all the answers you need.

Comment: sadly Gwendal I have looked through the docs and I still have the error with their examples.  I have created classes and structs and still I have the errors.